# How can i add functions to a thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I want to export pictures from raw data. Because of the size of data i want to divide the calculation in 4 threads. Concrete: it calculate 4 pics parallel. 
So every thread has to get a series of functions to calculate. Currently I have only found out how to start a thread with a new function. But not how the running thread can get another function added.

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( () => createSomething(dt, start, finish)));
myThread.Start();
```

My expectation:

```
myThread.add(new ThreadStart2( () => createSomethingelse(dt, start, finish)));
```

Comment: Consider using `async` / `await`, [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), `Parallel.ForEach` or Parallel LINQ (`Enumerable.AsParallel`). All of these are simpler approaches to parallelizing work that don't require you to manually manage threads and results.

Comment: That's not the way threads work. You don't add functions to a running thread. If you want to run another parallel task, start another thread.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You are launching a thread. The thread starts to run your function(lambda) in the background, runs in a non-blocking way and will eventually complete. It seems you would just call the `createSomethingelse(dt, start, finish)` inside the thread.

Comment: Just executing the code you have in the first section four times will give you 4 threads. You can store the `myThread` values in a list, or something, if needed.

Comment: cant you have a function `CreateAll()` in which you call all functions you need and the thread would call only `CreateAll()`?

Comment: Thanks, my fault... @JeroenMostert i try your solution

Comment: @Jules_96 What you ask is what `Task.Run` already does - it submits a Task with a function payload for execution by the runtime using a thread from a pool of already existing threads. Just use `Task.Run(()=>createSomething.....)`. With `await` you can even get results from that payload, eg `var x=await Task.Run(()=>Math.Pow(100,100));`

Comment: You probably want to look into a scheduling system. For example, if you're running an ASP.NET Core app, then Hangfire would be a great option.

Comment: What kind of calculations are you doing to the pictures? I am asking because if you are only doing single byte transformations, changing the value of each byte independently from any other byte, then using the Single Instruction to Multiple Data ([SIMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors)) technology you can achieve better performance using a single core than with multi-threading and 4 cores.

Answer (score 1):

Threads by themselves execute code, so you generally need some way for *that* code to perform polling for additional work if you want to add more functions to them.

If you're willing to use C# `Task`s instead of `Thread` objects directly, these can be chained via [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8), ie

```
var myTask = Task.Run(() => createSomething(dt, start, finish));
var myTask = myTask.ContinueWith(previous => createSomethingelse(dt, start, finish));
```

Note that execution may begin as soon as you call `Run`, but depends on threads in the thread pool.

All overloads of `ContinueWith` require functions which take the previous `Task` as parameter, but you could override that with an extension method pretty easily:

```
public static Task ContinueWith(this Task task, Action continuation) => 
    task.ContinueWith(_ => continuation());
```

Comment: ...or use the `await` keyword, to write less code and more readable.

Comment: Not if you're managing a series of other tasks and want to dynamically add more code onto them